# comparing two facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have facts like:

```
like(sara,'data base',3).
like(sara,'math',3).
like(sara,'physics',3).
like(sara,'law',3).
like(sara,'history',5).
like(sara,'science',1).
like(tom,'chemistry',3).
like(tom,'data base',2).
like(tom,'logic',3).
like(tom,'law',3).
like(tom,'history',3).
like(tom,'science',3).
:- dynamic same_like/3.
```

and I want to compare the facts to find a subject that both sara and tom like but with different level ,so what I do is that:

```
comp1 :-
    like(sara, NofC1, X),
    like(tom, NofC2, Y),
    NofC1 = NofC2,
    asserta( same_like(sara, NofC1, X) ),
    asserta( same_like(tom, NofC2, Y) ),
    same_like(sara, NC1, A),
    same_like(tom, NC2, B),
    NC1 = NC2,
    A =\= B, 
    write('sara and tom like the same subject " '),
    write(NC1),
    write(' " .But with different level, sara= '),
    write(A),
    write(' And tom = '),
    write(B),
    nl,
    fail.
```

the answer was right but there is a repetition in the answer :

```
sara and tom like the same subject " data base " .But with different level, sara= 3 And tom = 2
sara and tom like the same subject " data base " .But with different level, sara= 3 And tom = 2
sara and tom like the same subject " history " .But with different level, sara= 5 And tom = 3
sara and tom like the same subject " data base " .But with different level, sara= 3 And tom = 2
sara and tom like the same subject " science " .But with different level, sara= 1 And tom = 3
sara and tom like the same subject " history " .But with different level, sara= 5 And tom = 3
sara and tom like the same subject " data base " .But with different level, sara= 3 And tom = 2
false
```

.

the question is how can I remove this repetition??? :(

Answer (score 3):

You should not use asserta/1 without need. Your query could be far simpler

```
% define a reusable query
comp1(Argument, Person1, Level1, Person2, Level2) :-
    like(Person1, Argument, Level1),
    like(Person2, Argument, Level2),
    Person1 \= Person2, Level1 > Level2.
```

**edit** I changed `Level1 \= Level2` to `Level1 > Level2` to avoid duplicates

```
% use the query and display facilities
comp1 :-
    forall(comp1(Argument, Person1, Level1, Person2, Level2),
          format('sara and tom like the same subject " ~s  " .But with different level, ~s=~d And ~s=~d~n', [Argument, Person1, Level1, Person2, Level2])).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a cut after you find a match. For example after the nl.

```
  ....
  nl,
  !,
  fail.
```

And that prevents backtracking beyond that point. If that does not suit you you can experiment a bit with the location of the cut.

Comment: I do that but if I use ! not all answer will be printed :(